# [Android Emulator]Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I already clear data, clear cache, wipe data and disable automatic time zone but emulator still error:

> Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped

[image: android emulator error]

Comment: Create new virtual device, maybe this fix error

Comment: i'm working source code android. i build source code --> sdk include : files .img as: userdata.img, cache.img, ramdisk.img,... i create virtual device with files .img but it error. i create virtual device with files .img of google--> not error.